# git Push Error Messages When Deploying Over https

Tags: git, heroku, https

Today in heroku metric I observed this warning:

[image]

But at that time we did not deployed anything.

[Also I found about this warning in heroku documentation.](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1937)

What does this warning means?

Answer (score 0):

It's written in the documentation. It is Heroku "bug". You can try the suggested solution:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
heroku repo:reset -a YOUR_APP_NAME
```

After running these commands, try deploying your rejected changes again.